# How to trigger Typeahead using Enter/press only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-typeahead

I have an autocomplete search field ([Bootstrap-3-Typeahead](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead)), which currently is triggered whenever I use the `up/down arrow keys`.

I'm not sure why, but this is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  $("input[data-name='searchField']").typeahead({
    autoSelect: false,
    minLength: 2,
    delay: 0,
    fitToElement: true,
    items: 7,
    source: function(query, result) {
      [source-irrelevant]
    },
    updater:function(item) {
                      $("input[data-name='searchField']").val($(item).text());
                      window.location = item.url;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<input type='text' data-name="searchField" id="searchText" class='form-control typeahead' placeholder="Text..." data-provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off" />
```

I want to trigger the selection (window.location) **only when** the Enter key/Mouse Left-Click/Touch-press is being activated, and to use the arrow keys to navigate through the menu (I currently can navigate if fast enough, it's also triggering window.location though)